# symmetry of partial differential equations (Heat equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, symmetry, symmetric-functions

Morning everyone, I am doing some problem sheets for my class in Partial differential equations where we dont have an actual textbook. we are given a pack on notes. I am having an issue discerning what is meant by symmetry in the PDE's. We have first that: [One of these eigenvalue problems is symmetric and the other isn't.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1vQY.jpg)

\begin{align}
X'' - aX &= -\lambda X \quad \text{in } (0,\ell) \\
\text{with } X(0) &= X(\ell) = 0 \tag{1}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
X'' - aX' &= -\lambda X \quad \text{in } (0,\ell) \\
\text{with } X(0) &= X(\ell) = 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}

My problem comes next, in the problems we are asked to show that the equation in $(1)$ is symmetric and that the one in $(2)$ is not. Firstly, I would like to know what symmetry is in the case of these types of equations and then how to show it.
Thank you

Comment: I believe symmetry in this case means $X(x) = X(l-x)$. Then the second problem isn't symmetric due to the $X'$ term